# Why do I get an empty results to my query to get insights on my ad?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-insights

I'm trying to know how can I use Facebook API to retrieve metrics on ads. 
I published today an add linked to a page I'm in charge of.

I do not understand why the response to this query :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{{ad_id}}/insights?access_token= . 
{{user_access_token}}
```

is an empty data :

```
{
   "data": []
}
```

whereas in my ad manager I can see that I reached some people etc...

I also tried with fields (reach, impressions...) but I got the same answer.

It's my first question here, I tried to do my best to be clear but tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Does your access token include whatever permissions might be necessary for this call? Try and make it in Graph API Explorer first, the debug mode there can tell you if you get an empty result because of missing permissions.

Comment: I also tried on the Graph API Explorer getting the same results. However when I tried today it was working. I did exactly the same query than yesterday. 

I don't know why but finally it works. Maybe it takes some time after the publication of the ads.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, that is very likely. Insights aren’t necessarily “live” for all kinds of objects, and the documentation for ads insights explicitly states that some of the unique metrics “are time consuming to compute” ... so they are probably only available with a 24 hour delay or something.